# System not asking for my consent when using sudo multiple times

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

When I use `sudo` to install some software, update my system or any other action requiring my consent (*i.e.* to say `y` or `n` before the system can proceed), I am asked to approve the operation just the first time. If after that I decide to use `sudo` again it will not ask for my approval, and will just execute the task.

So my question is: why is that and how can I make it always ask for my approval?

Answer (score 7):

From `man sudoers`

```
 sudoers uses time stamp files for credential caching.  Once a user has
 been authenticated, the time stamp is updated and the user may then use
 sudo without a password for a short period of time (5 minutes unless
 overridden by the timeout option). 

 timestamp_timeout
                   Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo will ask
                   for a passwd again.  The timeout may include a frac-
                   tional component if minute granularity is insufficient,
                   for example 2.5.  The default is 5.  Set this to 0 to
                   always prompt for a password.  If set to a value less
                   than 0 the user's time stamp will never expire.  This
                   can be used to allow users to create or delete their
                   own time stamps via ``sudo -v'' and ``sudo -k'' respec-
                   tively.
```

This means you can run `visudo` and add this line:

```
Defaults timestamp_timeout=0
```

With that value we can see there's no credential caching:

```
$ sudo id
[sudo] password for sweh: 
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
$ sudo id
[sudo] password for sweh: 
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
$
```

Answer (score 4):

Sudo memorizes your password for a given time (default 5 minutes).
Some people find that convenient for some times when they enter many `sudo` prefixed commands in a row.
You can disable this feature by editing (as root) the file `/etc/sudoers`
and changing

```
timestamp_timeout=N
```

to

```
timestamp_timeout=0
```

Later if you find yourself wanting to do many commands as root you can always enter `sudo su` which will open a new shell as root.

credit: https://scottlinux.com/2012/08/04/change-sudo-default-password-timeout/

Comment: Or `sudo -s` which will open a shell directly (without `su`).